# Processing on files output by qgis:reprojectlayer have the original CRS from before reproject tool was used

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am writing a QGIS standalone Python command line tool. I check that all input shapefiles have a valid CRS with `layer.crs().isValid()` and then I reproject any files that are not already in ESPG:4326. One input file is originally in EPSG:3338. So, I call:

`processing.runalg('qgis:reprojectlayer', input.shp, 'ESPG:4326', reprojectOut.shp)`

the output 'reprojectOut.shp' has the correct CRS (4326) and correct .prj file and also displays properly even with 'On The Fly' disabled. So all seems well... until I try to extract a few features from the reprojected shapefile with:

`processing.runalg('qgis:extractbyexpression', reprojectOut.shp, expression, extractOut.shp)`

and somehow this output 'extractOut.shp' contains the correct features but has gone back to the original 'EPSG:3338' CRS. Is there something I am missing? Is there a reference to the original input file hiding somewhere? I have verified the filepaths are correct and tried passing both direct filepaths and also `QgsVectorLayer()` objects as input parameters. I am running QGIS 2.18.13 on Mac OSX High Sierra.

Comment: Can you confirm you used the correct terminology in your code (i.e. it is "**EPSG**" and not "ESPG")?

Comment: @Joseph I (sort of) found the issue but I'd be curious if you know what happened.  I called `layer=QgsVectorLayer('/path/to/fileA.shp','input',"ogr")` and then `processing.runalg('qgis:reprojectlayer',layer,crs.authid(), fileB.shp)` and then to save space I deleted fileA.shp.  I then renamed using `os.rename` fileB.shp to fileA.shp (and .dbf .qpj etc.) and reset data source with `layer.setDataSource('fileA.shp'..)`. Did I cut a reference with the renaming? Proceeding with name 'fileB.shp' works fine. Renaming back to 'fileA.shp' causes incorrect spatial reference on any future process outputs.

Comment: I would guess that some data from `layer` is still stored in memory. It's probably cleaner to redefine `layer` again (i.e. use `layer=QgsVectorLayer('/path/to/fileA.shp','input',"ogr")` after you renamed the shapefile).